# Magento get products matching the applied coupon criteria

Tags: magento, coupon

Can anyone help me find the products in current shopping cart matching the applied coupon criteria?

Actually I need to set the custom discount (50% on highest one) amount on any one matching products, By default Magento applied the 50% discount in all the matching products buy I need to apply discount on only one item.

I have make some Google and get some links on [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546410/magento-how-do-i-find-out-if-a-sales-rule-coupon-exists-for-a-product-item) and [http://www.magentocommerce.com/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/201516/#t303924), but not able to get any solution or suggestion.

Any help will be appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

e.g. I have four items in the cart in those two items matching the coupon criteria (Whatever we have set in condition), So by default Magento apply 50% discount (set in coupon) on these two items, but I want to give the discount only on one(highest price) out of these 2.

Comment: have you find solution for that? actually i have same problem now

Comment: Actually I don't get any proper solution at that time so make our custom code to find the all product matched that coupon code(we have only one coupon) and calculate the highest product price and set the custom discount price.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to select needed products in 'actions' tab? You may select only these products, for which you want to apply discount, there.

Also you may find 'Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To' configuration option there.

Comment: Thanks for reply :D
I have checked all but not able to get any solutions, e.g. I have four items in the cart in those two items matching the coupon criteria (Whatever we have set in condition), So by default Magento apply 50% discount (set in coupon) on these two items, but I want to give the discount only on one(highest price) out of these 2.

"Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" is work only for same item not for multiple items